# Executing SQL query with multiple values

Tags: sql, .net

I suspect the answer I require is already on stack overflow, somewhere, but I'm not sure what the function I need is, therefore don't quite know what to search for... I think it's going to be an array of sorts, or modulus?

Let me explain, and as a relative beginner, please be gentle. My current query reads:

```
SELECT c.C_Name, c.C_ID, q.Quote_Type from case c  inner join Quotes q
on q.Case_ID = c.ID where q.Quote_Type = 'Every 10 Years' and c.created_Date
like '" & ((ComboBox_Year.Text - 10) & monthNumber) & "%'
```

The user of my form has selected a month and year from comboboxes, and the query returns data from 10 years ago.

My question: Is there a way to return data for 20, 30, and 40 years ago without writing a new 'or' line for each?

Comment: Do you want to select data for 20, 30, and 40 years in one query?

Comment: If they select 20 etc the query will do that right now, assuming monthNumber changes accordingly

Comment: ideally. Not only do I have a 10 year query, I want to extend it to have additional lines for multiples of 5, 7, 8 years. If I have a query for each one, there would be 16 'or' lines! I thought there must be a better way...?

Comment: @MattDouhan - sorry Matt, should have clarified, 'monthNumber' is a conversion from the combobox selection of Jan, Feb, Mar, etc, to 01, 02, 03 etc.

Comment: @trickyb_uk you could use the IN clause and send a comma separated string in, like this select x from foo where date IN (10,20,30) ..... that way your IN clause can be anything you want but still only have one query

Comment: @MattDouhan - I was just writing to ask you to clarify that, but I think I got it and will give it a go tomorrow. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Might be able to use a combination of datepart and datediff. See if this helps at all, might not be exactly what you are after but hopefully can help lead you there.

```
SELECT 
  c.C_Name
  ,c.C_ID
  ,q.Quote_Type 
FROM Case c  
INNER JOIN Quotes q
ON q.Case_ID = c.ID 
WHERE q.Quote_Type = 'Every 10 Years' 
AND DATEPART(m, c.created_Date) = monthNumber
AND DATEDIFF(y, c.created_Date, CAST(CAST(ComboBox_Year.Text AS varchar) + '-' + CAST(monthNumber AS varchar) + '-01')  AS DATETIME) IN (10,20,30,40)
```

this would essentially be creating a datetime value from the monthnumber and text of the combo box (assuming that is the year selected) then getting a difference between the created date making sure the difference in years is in either 10, 20, 30, etc. All while ensuring that the created_Date month number matches what was selected. One query without any type of "or" statements, just one "in" statement.

Hope this helps!

Comment: that looks like something I can develop. I was struggling, with the earlier suggestions, to figure how to combine a 'LIKE' function and an 'IN' function - the two didn't seem compatible (in my limited understanding).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for their help with this one. I managed to get contact the DB creator - who reminded me that the 'created_date' field is not DATE formatted, but string (don't ask me why), which meant I could use SUBSTRING to split the year and month, carry out the calculation, then use the IN function as suggested by @MattDouhan.

As a development, can someone provide the method by which my query can be reduced from

> `... IN('10', '20', '30', '40', '50', etc, etc)`

to '...IN ('all multiples of 10)'

Does such a thing exist?